# PyQt5: Checkbox that distinguishes between one and double clicks?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Is it possible to have a checkbox that distinguishes between single and double clicks; e.g. ticked checkbox when clicked once, and filled checkbox when double clicked?

I basically need the user to select among some options and at the same time be able to pick one of those selected options as the primary choice. I thought normal selection can be done through one click and primary choice through double click. However, as mentioned in the answer in the below this will violates standard checkbox behaviour. So I’m open to any alternative option as well.

Comment: Qt supports QML and QtWidget-Frontends. The answer might depend. Which are you using?

Comment: I’m not sure how to answer your question?

Comment: If the answer below applies, the second line should be the solution: `from PyQt.5QtWidgets` => You are using QtWidgets. If you use some code that looks like this `CheckBox { text: "Pie" }` it would be QML/QtQuick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may want to ask if this is what you really want. The problem is that checkboxes are a well-recognized UI element that's practically always single click, so you are violating your users' expectations if you create a double-click checkbox.

EDIT: if you decide you want it, you might try the code below. The idea is to subclass QCheckBox and implement new handlers for click and double click, where double click always sets PartiallyChecked (the square) and single click cycles between Checked and Unchecked.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class DblClickCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        desired_state = QtCore.Qt.Unchecked if self.checkState() else QtCore.Qt.Checked
        self.setCheckState(desired_state)


class Example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = DblClickCheckBox('Our special checkbox')
        btn.setTristate()  # needed to have a 3-state checkbox
        lo = QVBoxLayout()
        lo.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(lo)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Is there any alternative standard option? I basically need the user to select among some options and at the same time pick one of those selected options as the primary choice.

Comment: If you want multiple options, the standard way is to use either radio buttons (for a few options) or a combo box (for a lot of options).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more a problem for [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/); as you already found out, using double click for a combobox isn't suggested for a number of reason, not only because of their well known UX behavior, but also because the double click feature has completely different meanings and the result might be difficult to understand to the user.

Also, consider that double click speed can be different according to the operating system and (possibly) user customization, and you'll also need to find a way to ensure that only one option is selected as default.

I've prepared three possible solutions for this:

1. a tristate mode, with a function that ensures that, if at least one option is selected, one option is automatically set as default;
2. a check/radio control, with the radio used to select the default option;
3. a combo that enables/disables items according to the selected options;

All of them have pros and cons. I believe that the first is less intuitive, the second is probably better (I choosed to put the radio on the right to avoid confusion), but the third is probably the best.

[image: the three possible implementations]

```
class TripleCheck(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.checks = []

    def addOption(self, text, checked=False):
        check = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(text)
        self.layout().addWidget(check)
        check.setTristate(True)
        self.checks.append(check)
        check.stateChanged.connect(lambda s, c=check: self.optionsChanged(c, s))
        self.optionsChanged(check, checked)

    def optionsChanged(self, i, state):
        currentCheck = self.checks[i]
        partially = []
        checked = []
        for c in self.checks:
            if c.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked:
                partially.append(c)
            elif c.checkState():
                checked.append(c)
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            for c in checked:
                if c.checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked and c != currentCheck:
                    c.blockSignals(True)
                    c.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)
                    c.blockSignals(False)
        elif state and not (checked):
            currentCheck.blockSignals(True)
            currentCheck.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            currentCheck.blockSignals(False)
        elif not state and partially and not checked:
            new = partially[0]
            new.blockSignals(True)
            new.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            new.blockSignals(False)


class RadioCheck(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Options'))
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Default'), 0, 1)
        self.checkGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.checkGroup.setExclusive(False)
        self.checkGroup.buttonToggled[int, bool].connect(self.optionsChanged)
        self.radioGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)

    def addOption(self, text, checked=False):
        check = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(text)
        layout = self.layout()
        row = layout.rowCount()
        self.checkGroup.addButton(check, row - 1)
        radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton()
        radio.setEnabled(False)
        self.radioGroup.addButton(radio, row - 1)
        layout.addWidget(check, row, 0)
        layout.addWidget(radio, row, 1)
        if checked:
            check.setChecked(True)

    def optionsChanged(self, i, state):
        radio = self.radioGroup.button(i)
        radio.setEnabled(state)
        if not state and radio.isChecked():
            radio.setChecked(False)
            for r in self.radioGroup.buttons():
                if r.isEnabled():
                    r.setChecked(True)
                    break
            else:
                checkedRadio = self.radioGroup.checkedButton()
                if checkedRadio:
                    self.radioGroup.setExclusive(False)
                    checkedRadio.setChecked(False)
                    self.radioGroup.setExclusive(True)
        elif state:
            if not self.radioGroup.checkedButton():
                radio.setChecked(True)


class ComboCheck(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Default:'))
        self.combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo, 0, 1)
        self.checkGroup = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self)
        self.checkGroup.setExclusive(False)
        self.checkGroup.buttonToggled[int, bool].connect(self.optionsChanged)

    def addOption(self, text, checked=False):
        check = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(text)
        check.setChecked(checked)
        layout = self.layout()
        row = layout.rowCount()
        self.checkGroup.addButton(check, row - 1)
        layout.addWidget(check, row, 0, 1, 2)
        self.combo.addItem(text)
        if self.combo.count() == 1:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        self.optionsChanged(row - 1, checked)

    def optionsChanged(self, i, state):
        current = self.combo.currentIndex()
        model = self.combo.model()
        item = model.item(i, 0)
        if not state:
            item.setFlags(item.flags() &~QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        else:
            item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        enabled = []
        for r in range(model.rowCount()):
            if model.item(r, 0).flags() & QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled:
                enabled.append(r)
        if current in enabled:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(current)
        elif i in enabled:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(i)
        elif enabled:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(enabled[0])
        else:
            self.combo.setCurrentIndex(-1)


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)

        testWidgets = []

        for testClass, name in ((TripleCheck, 'Triple'), (RadioCheck, 'Radio'), (ComboCheck, 'Combo')):
            group = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(name)
            layout.addWidget(group)
            test = testClass()
            QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(group).addWidget(test)
            testWidgets.append(test)

            test.addOption('option 1')
            test.addOption('option 2')
            test.addOption('option 3', True)
            test.addOption('option 4')
```

Comment: I really liked your alternative options. I wish I could select two answers for my question.

Comment: @BehzadJamali Don't worry, marking the other answer as accepted is correct, since it's the one that actually answers the question at hand.